# Changing the order of creation of instances is changing their behaviour Python

Tags: python, oop, python-2.7

I have a class which takes a array and calculates an answer. The Class is as follows :

```
class Delish:
    ing = []
    rmax = []
    rmin = []
    lmax = []
    lmin = []
    answer = 0

    def rightmax(self):
        # sets rmax

    def rightmin(self):
        # sets rmin



    def leftmax(self):
        # sets lmax

    def leftmin(self):
        # sets lmin


    def calculate(self):
        #calulates answer

    def __init__(self,array):
        self.ing = list(array)
        self.rightmax()
        self.rightmin()
        self.leftmax()
        self.leftmin()
        self.calculate()
```

Now this gives output 4 13 (which is correct)

```
b = Delish([1,1,-1,-1])
a = Delish([1,2,3,4,5])


print a.answer,b.answer
```

And this gives output 7 13 (which is wrong)

```
a = Delish([1,2,3,4,5])
b = Delish([1,1,-1,-1]) 

print a.answer,b.answer
```

I cannot put the full code as it is a part of a live programming contest. But I want to know what is causing this weird behaviour. All of the methods are working on self. variables only. Therefore all the objects should be independent from each other right?

I can add details if it doesn't gives much of the algorithm away. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**In Python, declare instance variables within the constructor**

What you're actually doing is declaring **class variables**. If you want **instance variables** in Python, you will need to declare them them in your constructor:

```
class Delish:
  # This is a class variable. 
  # All instances can refer to this as self.foo
  foo = 42 

  def __init__(self,array):
    self.ing = [] # This is an instance variable
    self.rmax = []
    self.rmin = []
    self.lmax = []
    self.lmin = []
    self.answer = 0
    self.ing = list(array)
    self.rightmax()
    self.rightmin()
    self.leftmax()
    self.leftmin()
    self.calculate()
```

Answer (score 0):

*You are probably a C++/Java programmer.*

All your fields, except for `ing` which is assigned and thus overwritten in `__init__`, are *class fields*, that is, they are shared between all the instances of yor class. Move your instance initialisation to `__init__`:

```
class Delish:
    # Nothing here

    def __init__(self, array):
        self.ing = list(array)
        rmax = []
        rmin = []
        lmax = []
        lmin = []
        answer = 0

        self.rightmax()
        self.rightmin()
        self.leftmax()
        self.leftmin()
        self.calculate()
```